# How do the Earps and Henry Hooker know each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, tombstone

In **Tombstone**, Henry Hooker is giving shelter to the sick "Doc Holliday":

[image]

But how did the Earps and Henry Hooker know each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we first see the Earps it is 1879 and the Gunfight at the OK Corral does not actually take place until 1881. So the movie takes place over a couple of years which is plenty of time for them to get to know each other.

[**Henry Hooker**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Hooker) was a prosperous rancher in Arizona at the time having been there since 1867. He would have had a vested interest in maintaining law and order and would have made an effort to get to know the town marshal

> Hooker, who was referred by the honorary title of "Colonel Hooker", arrived in the Arizona Territory with the profits from his turkey venture in 1867. He built up a cattle operation supplying beef to the military. He brought 10,000 Texas Longhorns from Texas in 1872
>
> <sup>Wikipedia</sup>